# link to a pdf file with symfony2 and assetic

Tags: php, symfony, hyperlink, assetic

I use syomfony2 and assetic. How can i create a link to a pdf-file in my web folder?

It works great for images but there is no tag for pdf

```
{% image '@myBundle/Resources/public/pdf/dok.pdf'%}
<img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="my image"/>
{% endimage %}
```

what i want to do is a simple `<a href...>Download pdf here</a>`

Answer (score 6):

`<a href="{{ asset('bundles/my/Resources/public/pdf/dok.pdf') }}">Download PDF!</a>`
You don't need to use assetic for this, it doesn't really make sense in the context of downloading a PDF.